# Using a "custom" font when creating a PDF with Syncfusion in .NET Core

Tags: pdf, asp.net-core, syncfusion

I am trying to create a PDF it .NET Core, and I am using Syncfusion's PDF library to do it.

According to their [docs](https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/working-with-text#drawing-text-using-different-fonts), I should be able to use the following code:

```
PdfFont font = new PdfTrueTypeFont(new Font("Arial", 14));
```

However, the only CTORs I have are:

```
public PdfTrueTypeFont(Stream fontStream, float size);
public PdfTrueTypeFont(PdfTrueTypeFont prototype, float size);
public PdfTrueTypeFont(Stream fontStream, float size, PdfFontStyle style);
```

These are the Syncfusion packages I have installed

```
"Syncfusion.Compression.Portable": "15.1120.0.37",
"Syncfusion.Pdf.Portable": "15.1120.0.37"
```

I also tried the `MVC` versions as well, in place of the `Portable` versions.

I'm using the latest .NET Core, "netstandard1.6"

Am I missing a package, doing something wrong, or is this just not supported in .NET Core yet?

My end game is to be able to write text to a PDF in any of the web-safe fonts () from a .NET Core Library. I also need to have a way to be able to measure the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `PdfTrueTypeFont` does not have support for giving font name in .Net Core, you can give .ttf font as `Stream` to the `PdfTrueTypeFont`.

```
string path = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath + "/Font/Arial.ttf";  

Stream fontStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);  

//Create a new PDF true type font.  
PdfTrueTypeFont tFont = new PdfTrueTypeFont(fontStream, 12,PdfFontStyle.Regular);
```

We have created a sample to draw text in PDF with help of both `PdfTrueTypeFont` and `PdfStandardFont`. And also, used a variable to measure the size of the given text.

Please find the sample from the below link:
http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/174333/ze/sample-2079659962

Please refer the below link for supported features in .Net Core:
https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/supported-and-unsupported-features

Comment: Thank you. Does the font stream really need write access to the font as well?